# how to fix this error it apear when i am going to create react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rjgovinda/.npm/_logs/2021-07-28T05_32_14_082Z-debug.log
rjgovinda@rjgovinda-X541NA:~/Desktop/Program$ npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rjgovinda/.npm/_logs/2021-07-28T05_3

Comment: As the error says, the user with witch you are trying to access '/usr/local/lib' doesn't have the necessary permissions. Try executing as root or change the permissions of the folder.

Comment: If you are using windows, open command prompt or shell as an ADMIN using `RUN AS ADMIN`.. In Linux, it would be `sudo <command-to-exec>`. Since u do not have write permission, the above solution may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try `npx create-react-app app-name --force` and also check your internet connection
if this solution not work then try to reinstall your node module